# Strange line in the korn shell script

Tags: shell-script

I know it is  may be stupid question. I have several lines, which set up some important directories. After that the line is:

```
parse_args $@
```

However, I don't see any argument in the program.
Any idea about this? I believe that we have to send real arguments:

parse_args $a $b $c

Comment: Where would the values for $a, etc. come from?

Comment: You should read here, http://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/solaris-forte/IPE/dbx/dbx88h.html

Comment: I know this. What I ask you, is we cannot just make a function call parsee_args $@, We should make it parse_args "$a, $b, $c", where they have values (don't matter what kind and where it comes from). And in aolling program we can catch them he $@, and in the loop put them to different variables. Am I wrong?

Comment: you understand that `$@` refers to the aggregation of all arguments passed, right? so it means the full list of arguments passed in when invoking the script in which the reference appears.